# ajax and user control in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have a VB .net application in which i have an aspx page (say default.aspx). I'm loading a usercontrol (say usercontrol.ascx) in it. I need to write an *ajax code* in the page (in aspx page or in ascx control) *which should call a method* (say test()) *in the user control.*

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "",
                data: "{'userid':" + userId + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("In error  ");
                }
            });
```

what I can give as *url* in this ajax method in order to call a method in the user control?

Comment: the method you want to call it is in web service or aspx.cs page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call webmethod in usercontrol. either you have to put your webmethod inside the page or in webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the control name and name of your method.

For example:

```
url: "usercontrol.ascx/test",
```